# code in if __name__ == "__main__" doesn't get run for Flask app on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I have a Flask app with code like the following in `application.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    print('loading model...')

    model = load_model('my_model.h5')

    print('model loaded')

    application.run()
```

Upon running `python application.py` in my local environment, this code executes. However, in my Elastic Beanstalk environment, this code doesn't get run as there is no `print('loading model...')` statements in the logs and the application fails with a "model is undefined" error when the model needs to get used (as it must have never been loaded when the application started). Why is this behaving different to my local environment and how can I ensure code is run when the application is started on Elastic Beanstalk? I'm using the default free  t2.micro for this example.

Comment: Can I see how your file is structured? Is there some link to a GitHub repo?

Comment: https://github.com/wanshun123/Facial-Beauty-Prediction/blob/master/application.py